# Broken While Loop Using Macros in Racket

Tags: loops, macros, racket

I am implementing a while loop using Racket macros. My question is, can somebody please explain to me why the following code produces an infinite macro expansion loop? The last statement just before the recursive while call - body - decrements the value of x by 1, so you would think that we will be marching towards the condition where x will become equal to 0. But I'm obviously missing something. Thank you in advance!

```
(let ([x 5])
(while (> x 0)
     (displayln x)
     (set! x (- x 1))))    

 (define-syntax while
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((while c var body)
        (if
           c
          (begin
           var
           body
          (while c var  body))
          (void)))))
```

Comment: Your expansion contain the expression you originally expanded so every expansion warrants at least one new one. You need to have the expression not have itself in the result. Perhaps named `let`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are not functions. They *generate code*, they apply at *compile-time*, and they know nothing about runtime values. This means that even if you write this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (some-macro)
  (displayln "hello!"))

(when #f
  (some-macro))
```

…the use of `some-macro` will *still* be expanded, and the program will be transformed to this one:

```
(when #f
  (displayln "hello!"))
```

This is **really important to understand** when working with macros: macros are literally code replacement tools. When a macro is expanded, the use of the macro is literally replaced with the code produced by the macro. This can cause problems with recursive macros, since if you’re not careful, macroexpansion will never terminate. Consider this example program:

```
(define-syntax-rule (recursive-macro)
  (when #f
    (displayln "hello!")
    (recursive-macro)))

(recursive-macro)
```

After a single macroexpansion step, the use of `(recursive-macro)` will expand to this:

```
(when #f
  (displayln "hello!")
  (recursive-macro))
```

Now, if `recursive-macro` were a function, the fact that it appears inside the `when` form would not matter—it would simply never be executed. But `recursive-macro` *isn’t* a function, it’s a macro, and it will be expanded regardless of the fact that the branch will never be taken at runtime. This means that after a second macroexpansion step, the program will be transformed to this:

```
(when #f
  (displayln "hello!")
  (when #f
    (displayln "hello!")
    (recursive-macro)))
```

I think you can see where this is going. The nested `recursive-macro` uses will never stop expanding, and the program will quickly grow unboundedly large.

---

It’s possible that you are unsatisfied by this. Given that the branch will *never* be taken, why does the expander stupidly continue expanding? Well, `recursive-macro` is a very silly macro, as it wouldn’t be very useful to ever write a macro that expands to code that will never be executed. Instead, imagine we modified the definition of `recursive-macro` slightly:

```
(define-syntax-rule (recursive-macro)
  (when (zero? (random 2))
    (displayln "hello!")
    (recursive-macro)))
```

Now it’s clear that the expander *can’t* know how many times the recursive calls will be executed, since the behavior is random, and the random numbers generated will be different on every program execution. Given that expansion is happening at compile-time, not at runtime, it just doesn’t make sense for the expander to try and account for runtime information.

This is what’s wrong with your `while` macro. You seem to be expecting that `while` will behave like a function call, and a recursive use of `while` in a runtime branch that isn’t taken won’t be expanded. This is just not true: macros are expanded at compile-time, regardless of runtime information. Indeed, you should think of the macroexpansion process as a transformation that produces a program without any macros in it as output, which is only then executed.

---

With that in mind, how can you fix it? Well, when writing a macro, you need to think of yourself as writing a tiny compiler: your macro needs to implement its functionality by transforming the input code into some code that performs the desired behavior, *entirely* defined using simpler language features. In this case, a very simple way to implement a loop in Racket is [a named-`let` loop](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), like this one:

```
(let ([x 5])
  (let loop ()
    (when (> x 0)
      (displayln x)
      (set! x (- x 1))
      (loop))))
```

This makes it easy to implement your `while` construct: you just need to write a macro that transforms `while` into the equivalent named-`let`:

```
(define-syntax-rule (while c body ...)
  (let loop ()
    (when c
      body ...
      (loop))))
```

This will do what you expect.

Of course, this macro isn’t very idiomatic Racket. Racketeers prefer to avoid `set!` and other forms of mutation, and they’d just use [one of the built-in `for` constructs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) to write iteration without assignment. Still, it’s perfectly reasonable if you’re just experimenting with the macro system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I have a followup question. In light of what you have explained, is it then fair to say that macros in Racket should never be used recursively since they will always exhibit this type of behavior (i.e. expand indefinitely at compile time)?

Comment: @AlexanderNenartovich It’s fine to have recursive macros, but just like with recursive functions, they need to have a base case, and that base case needs to be reached *at compile-time*. For example, the most logical implementation of `cond` is to recursively translate it into nested `if` forms, and since each recursive step handles one clause, the base case is the empty `(cond)` form.

Comment: Would it be possible to re-write my attempt using recursive macros and add a base case that can be reached at compile time? Just curious.

Comment: @AlexanderNenartovich No, because your loop’s base case is at runtime—you don’t know until the program is executed how many times the loop should run. But with `cond`, you know at compile-time exactly how many clauses there are (since the user writes them explicitly). Put another way, writing a recursive `while` macro would be doing loop *unrolling*, and you’d need to know exactly how many iterations would take place ahead of time.

Comment: Thank you again! In the solution that you wrote using named let, does loop serve as a label that the program jumps to from the last line and executes the body of if the condition c is true? Is this basically Racket's way of writing a loop?

Comment: @AlexanderNenartovich As I said in the answer, most people would use the `for` family of iteration constructs to write loops in Racket, but [the part of The Racket Guide I linked to](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) documents named `let`.